# ImportError, No viewers found

Tags: python, importerror, enthought

I am trying to run FiPy using Enthought Python Distribution (EPD) followed the instruction from [Fipy's official website](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/MACOSX-INSTALLATION.html#).

I have installed the FiPy 3.1.4  and Pysparse  using the EPD's package manager. And I just to try to run the example (the diffusion example from FiPy) to see if this works. It gives the following error:

```
        %run "/Users/apple/Documents/FiPy-3.1/examples/diffusion/mesh1D.py"
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
        /Users/apple/Documents/FiPy-3.1/examples/diffusion/mesh1D.py in <module>()
        792 if __name__ == '__main__':
        793     import fipy.tests.doctestPlus
        --> 794     exec(fipy.tests.doctestPlus._getScript())
        795 

        <string> in <module>()

        /Users/apple/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fipy/viewers/__init__.pyc in Viewer(vars, title, limits, FIPY_VIEWER, **kwlimits)
    131             raise ImportError, "`%s` viewer not found" % FIPY_VIEWER
    132         else:
    --> 133             raise ImportError, "No viewers found. Run `python setup.py egg_info` or similar."
    134 
    135     if len(vars) > 0:

    ImportError: No viewers found. Run `python setup.py egg_info` or similar.
```

Then I run the python setup.py egg_info on the terminal under the FiPy directory. It seems generate several files. Under the file "entry_points.txt" it shows:

```
[fipy.viewers]
gist = fipy.viewers.gistViewer:GistViewer
gnuplot = fipy.viewers.gnuplotViewer:GnuplotViewer
matplotlib = fipy.viewers.matplotlibViewer:MatplotlibViewer
mayavi = fipy.viewers.mayaviViewer:MayaviClient
```

However, even if I installed the matplotlib and mayavi through the EPD package manger, the same error still occurs.